# Azure sb lite connection string and event hub compatible name

Tags: c#, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to make an UWP app for receiving messages from Azure IoT hub, and I found some example code that use Azure sb lite, but problem is in these lines of code:

```
var factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(Config.ConnectionStringAzureSbLite);
var client = factory.CreateEventHubClient(Config.EventHubCompatibleName);
```

Where can I find out what is my `ConnectionStringAzureSbLite` and what is my `EventHubCompatibleName`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get these from the Azure portal. Look at the settings for your IoT Hub in the "Messaging" settings.  See the section "How to read from Event Hubs-compatible endpoints" here:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-devguide/